# operand should contain 1 column select query mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT events.*, location.*, provider.name  as provider_name,provider.name_ar  as provider_name_ar,
 category.name  as category_name,
 category.name_ar as category_name_ar,
sub_category.name  as sub_category_name,sub_category.name_ar as sub_category_name_ar,
(SELECT slider.* FROM slider WHERE slider.subID=events.eventID and slider.type=2) as images,
(SELECT event_benefits.* ,benefits.* FROM `event_benefits` INNER JOIN benefits ON benefits.benefitsID =event_benefits.benefitID WHERE event_benefits.eventID=events.eventID) as benefit,
(SELECT event_kids_tek.*  FROM event_kids_tek WHERE event_kids_tek.eventID=events.eventID) as Ticket ,
(SELECT media.*  FROM media WHERE media.subID=events.eventID and media.type=1 and media.status=1) as Ticket ,
(SELECT event_kids_age.* FROM event_kids_age WHERE eventID=events.eventID) as kid_age,
(SELECT event_kids_gender.* FROM event_kids_gender WHERE eventID=events.eventID) as gender
 FROM events 
INNER JOIN category ON category.categoryID =events.cat_id
INNER JOIN sub_category ON events.sub_id = sub_category.subCatID
INNER JOIN provider ON provider.providerID=events.prv_id
INNER JOIN location ON location.id=events.loc_id

WHERE events.status=1
```

That query though gives me an error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

What stumps me is that I would think that this query would work with no problem. Selecting columns, then selecting two more from another table, and continuing on from there. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Is there a simple fix to this, or another way to write my query?

Comment: All these `(SELECT table.*......)` are wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149404/how-can-i-return-1-row-from-a-subquery-in-select-statement-if-subquery-has-more

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
SELECT x,
       ( SELECT ... ) AS y,
       z
     FROM ...
```

That subquery (for `y`) is expected to deliver *one* value, not several.

To get multiple columns from two tables (as you are doing for other tables):

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, b.c3, b.c4
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON (how the two tables are related);
```